# Python Selenium - continue to run script after manually pass Captcha

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver, captcha

I need to register a lot of people in a company's system but there's a captcha in the login screen that I want to solve it manually before running the script to automatically fill the data in the system. Is there any way to make the webdriver "wait" for me to solve the captcha and then continue to run the script (find the XPaths and fill the data in)?

Comment: asking for `input()` pauses running until manual entering

Comment: put some time.sleep(5) for 5 or 10 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```py
driver.wait.until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath"))).click()
```

for the button.

Try to add the screenshot or link of the web page

Answer (score 0):

I would use keyboard input.
Add a while True loop which breaks when you enter a keyboard combination.

```
import time
import keyboard

""" Script until captcha """

print('Stopping script for captcha.\nPress "ctrl+shift+x" to continue script')
while True:        
    if keyboard.is_pressed("ctrl+shift+x"):
        print('Script will continue in 2 seconds :)')
        time.sleep(2)
        break
        
""" Rest of script """
```